# Cucumber + Capybara - Difficulty filling a form - Element not found

Tags: testing, cucumber, capybara

I am doing my **hello world** test application in an already completed project and am experiencing some scenarios and am puzzled by what I am seen is happening.

### I am using:

- `Capybara`
- `Cucumber`
- And selinium web driver for when we need `Javascript`
- All of this on a Sinatra app
- RSpec separately, but that is not the interest.

### Problem:

When running cucumber tests as `cucumber features/#{feature_name}.feature`, and given that I am on a specific page. I can find elements by `CSS ID` but can't click on them.

```
When(/^I log in with email "(.*?)" and password "(.*?)"$/) do |email, password|
  step %{I am on login page}

  expect(page).to have_css('#login-form')
  expect(page).to have_css('#login-button')

  within("#login-form") do 
    fill_in '#username', with: email
    fill_in '#password', with: password
    click_button 'dfalkjsdfalsdkfja dflkjasdf alkdsjfasd lfkjsf s'  # Which should fail, but odesn't :'(
  end

  click_button 'Sign In'
  # click_button '#login-button'   # This fails
end
```

The following test will pass even if I use a completely random non existent ID for `#login-form`.  And as you see I have a button with some silly text. Also if I give it as an ID, no difference. The test passes.

But when I use them alone without the within block, the the elements are not found.

But above you see `expect(page).to` statements find them.

The above is some what similar to the example I see in the `Capybara` repo.

### My Questions:

- Can I use `CSS selectors` to target ex: `#login-form`
- Should using a non existing selector in the `within` block fail? My case it doesn't.
- Why is some thing like `fill_in '#password', with: 'password'` fail saying element not found while the above assertion seems to find it?
- I am a newby, so a suggestion where things might have gone wrong in terms of setting up. Example link would also be great.

### PS:

Forgot to ask, considering the example in the repo, what is 'Email' in the following `fill_in` block. Doesn't seem to be a id of the element.

```
fill_in 'Email', :with => 'user@example.com'
```

### Update

After some playing around, I find the following working (finding the element and filling/clicking it). But the `within` block doesn't fill in the form. Can any config effect the `within` block  as I explain.

```
When(/^I log in with email "(.*?)" and password "(.*?)"$/) do |email, password|
  step %{I am on login page}

  find('form#login-form').find('input#username').set email
  find('form#login-form').find('input#password').set password
  find('form#login-form').find('#login').click

  within("form#login-form") do 
    fill_in 'input#username', with: email
    fill_in 'input#password', with: password
    click_button '#login'
  end

end
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue of a non-existent selector in a `within` block. It does fail for me. For your other questions, the main crux of the problem is that `fill_in` and `click_button` do not support CSS selectors - see the [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions).

Comment: @JustinKo: I don't think this is a problem with Cucumber/Capybara. I rather think its some config issue may be. The documentation, Isn't it saying 'Name, ID or label text'. The form I am using isn't having a label, so will have to rely on Name and ID. Name is as such 'user[username]' which I tried.

Comment: Unless Capybara has changed recently, your two attempts (the `find` vs the `fill_in` are doing 2 different things. The `find` approach is looking for an element `<input id="username>`, where as the `fill_in` is looking for an element `<input id="input#username">`. It should be `fill_in 'username'`, where the locator is *not* a CSS-selector (ie no starting #).

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that now. But shouldn't it raise an error if the elements are bit found. I am bit in to testing, but noticed it once when I changed a attribute ID.